# What to do with a class where one particular variable is sometimes not used

Tags: java

Beginner question here.  I'm writing a Java program that queries a public API on the internet to retrieve details of discussions on a forum.  The data comes back as JSON and I'm parsing that into Java objects to be used in my program.

A discussion normally contains five attributes, i.e. the five public variables.  However, in response to a limited number of specific search types, the number of comments is not returned.

Is there a 'best' (in terms of object oriented programming) way to deal with this sort of scenario?  My first attempt is below, where I have simply written two constructors, one that assigns a value to numberOfComments, and one that does not.

This doesn't seem like a great solution - what happens if another class creates a DiscussionDetails object, uses the constructor that does not populate numberOfComments, but then later tries to use the numberOfComments field?

I thought that maybe it should be split into two classes, where DiscussionDetails has no numberOfComments field, and DiscussionDetailsSpecialised is a subclass with an additional numberOfComments field.  This feels a bit like overkill to me, for the sake of one single field.

Or maybe there's a convention that such a variable is initialised with a particular value like 'false' or '-1' or something?

Are there other, better approaches that an experienced programmer would use for this kind of situation?

I know the example is trivial, but I'm using it to try to illustrate my question as simply as possible.

```
/**
 * Wrapper for a set of JSON data returned from an API
 */
public class DiscussionDetails 
    {
    public String discussionID;
    public String discussionName;
    public String discussionURL;
    public String submittedDate;
    public String numberOfComments;

    /**
     * Constructor that populates all fields
     */
    public DiscussionDetails(String discussionID, String discussionName, String discussionURL, String submittedDate, String numberOfComments)
        {
        this.discussionID = discussionID;
        this.discussionName = discussionName;
        this.discussionURL = discussionURL;
        this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
        this.numberOfComments = numberOfComments;
        }

    /**
     * Constructor method to use when the number of comments is unknown, which happens in certain specific cases
     */
    public DiscussionDetails(String discussionID, String discussionName, String discussionURL, String submittedDate)
        {
        this.discussionID = discussionID;
        this.discussionName = discussionName;
        this.discussionURL = discussionURL;
        this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
        } 
    }
```

Comment: If there are no comments wouldn't `numberOfComments` be set 0 and that's the end of it? Or are you trying to capture "there might be comments but I don't know based on the query I did" ?

Comment: The latter.  There are several different types of API query used to retrieve discussion details, such as newest discussions, all discussions submitted by a particular member, a set of discussions matching a keyword search etc.  Depending on the type of query performed, the response either contains `numberOfComments`or it doesn't, regardless of whether the discussion actually has comments.  i.e. it's entirely possible that the response from the API contains no indication of the number of comments, despite the fact the discussion contains several comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been traditionally solved with "special" values (values that obviously make no sense, eg: `-1` for a count) or `null` (which in a sense is *the most special* value).

The "best" way to deal with this is, IMHO, `java.util.Optional`: clients have to check if a value is present when they wish to use it and `Optional` makes this explicit, avoiding the common source of bugs of a client forgetting to check.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `java.util.Optional` - thanks for bringing it to my attention.  I'll read up on it.

Comment: @Hoof-Hearte. Using `Optional` is the only simple way to model your use case. Using `Optional.empty()` you will tell the client code that you were unable to determine the number of comments.

Comment: I got a few good responses that gave me things to read up on / think about, but I'm accepting this as the answer because it both states the traditional way to deal with the specific question, and offers an alternative approach.

Answer (score 1):

One way to solve this is with a builder.  Your example is good, but a builder can help make it more obvious what's going on.

```
/**
 * Wrapper for a set of JSON data returned from an API
 */
public class DiscussionDetails 
    {
    public String discussionID;
    public String discussionName;
    public String discussionURL;
    public String submittedDate;
    public String numberOfComments;

   public static class Builder{
      private DiscussionDetails dd = new DiscussionDetails();

      public discussionID(String discussionID) {
        dd.discussionID = discussionID;
        return this;
      }

      public discussionName(String discussionName) {
        dd.discussionName= discussionName;
        return this;
      }

      public discussionURL(String discussionURL) {
        dd.discussionURL= discussionURL;
        return this;
      }

      public submittedDate(String submittedDate) {
        dd.submittedDate= submittedDate;
        return this;
      }

      public numberOfComments(String numberOfComments) {
        dd.numberOfComments= numberOfComments;
        return this;
      }

      public DiscussionDetails build() {
        return dd;
      }

   }


 }
```

This can make your instantiation a little cleaner, especially with optional fields or a lot of fields.

You would use this like:

```
DiscussionDetails details = 
    new DiscussionDetails.Builder()
         .discussionID("1")
         .discussionName("Name")
         .build();
```

In this particular case, I've set 2 of the fields. The other fields would be null, or the default value.  With some extra code, this gives you a lot of flexibility and arguably makes the code easier to read.

If you need to enforce certain fields being set, you can add more methods in the Builder class itself, or throw an error from the build method.

Comment: That led me to some interesting reading on design patterns, and gives me a bit of homework to do, so thank you for that!  I'm not sure it's a fix for my issue though, i.e. having fields in my class that may not be set.  Maybe I'm overthinking it and having unset fields is not that big a deal - it just seemed to me like I had a bit of a flaw in my design.

Comment: @Hoof-Hearted  There is nothing wrong with having some fields in a class that aren't set, although too many, and you might want to think about the model itself.  A discussion object would be a good example.  There might not be comments or the user might not provide a URL, for example.  The base object is still the same, and it really doesn't make sense to have two objects, a discussion object and a discussionWithoutComments object.

Answer (score 1):

The "special" value for handling a case when there is no value for a given property is a `null` value (`nil` in some languages). However, you should document this in your code so that the client of the code knows that the `numberOfComments` can be `null` - forgetting about it and trying to use the value ends with one of the most common exceptions - `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0):

call this in your constructor

```
    public class DiscussionDetails {

  public String discussionID;
  public String discussionName;
  public String discussionURL;
  public String submittedDate;
  public String numberOfComments;

  /**
   * Constructor that populates all fields
   */
  public DiscussionDetails(String discussionID, String discussionName, String discussionURL,
      String submittedDate, String numberOfComments) {
    this(discussionID, discussionName, discussionURL, submittedDate);
    this.numberOfComments = numberOfComments;
  }

  /**
   * Constructor method to use when the number of comments is unknown, which happens in certain
   * specific cases
   */
  public DiscussionDetails(String discussionID, String discussionName, String discussionURL,
      String submittedDate) {
    this.discussionID = discussionID;
    this.discussionName = discussionName;
    this.discussionURL = discussionURL;
    this.submittedDate = submittedDate;
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes one of the constructors more concise and gets rid of a bit of duplication, so that seems like a good thing and probably improves the code.  I'm not sure how it answers my question though, unless the implication is that it's OK to leave the `numberOfComments` uninitialised if the response from the API doesn't contain a `numberOfComments` element?

Comment: @Hoof-Hearted I already said that Lombok is good solution for minimizing boilerplate code. and use `null` checks as by default all non primitives has value of null. and probably you would use correct objects for your discussionDetails object. like `String id; String name; String url; LocalDate submitted; Long numberOfComments`